# Javascript Object [object Object] has no method 'bPopup'

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, bpopup

I am using bpopup to display my [popup](http://plugins.jquery.com/bpopup/). Interesting thing to note here is that when I click my button, popup appears, but if I re click that button , error comes in my console that `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'bPopup'` . Sometimes popup appears two times, and when I click third time I encounter same error.  Here is part of my code :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bpopup.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#signin").click(function(){
      $("#popup").bPopup({
        loadUrl: "<?php echo site_url().'xyz/signin'?>",
            });

  });
  });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="popup" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div style="float:right;display:inline-block"><button id="signin">Sign In</button></div>
  </body>
```

EDIT : I figured out what problem is, when I click sign in , I see there is a new element created with  , so Jquery is loaded again and if jQuery is loaded twice then bpopup will not work. Any idea why this script tag is coming ?

Comment: Load jQuery before the plugin - and wrap your code inside `$(document).ready(function() {...});`

Comment: Sorry, but in my actual code I have placed jquery first, still its not working , and everything is inside document.ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I was including jQuery again in my sign up form which was loading with pop up, so on twice loading jQuery , bPopup will not work. Thanks guys for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of script inclusion (*you need to include jquery before including your script*)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bpopup.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, but in my actual code I have placed jquery first, still its not working , and everything is inside document.ready.

Comment: I figured out what problem is, when I click sign in , I see there is a new element created with <script async src="ajax....."></script> , so Jquery is loaded again and if jQuery is loaded twice then bpopup will not work. Any idea why this script tag is coming ?